# boot() unable to use variable within creating() callback

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

When creating a user within `User.php` I'm trying to define a UUID, create a directory, and then add it to the user on the DB. The folder creates successfully with the UUID but it will not get passed into the `creating()` callback.

```
/**
    * Create the user when this class is called
    *
    * @return void
    */
public static function boot()
{
    // Setup parent
    parent::boot();

    // Create UUID
    $uuid = Str::uuid();

    // Create user directory on S3
    Storage::disk('s3')->makeDirectory('users/' . $uuid);

    // Assign UUID to new user
    self::creating(function ($model) {
        $model->id = $uuid;
    });
}
```

`$model->id = $uuid;` is undefined here and results in no value.

Comment: how do u create the user, plz post the code. and is `id` string?

Comment: I'm using the default Laravel registration features...

If I pass the `Str::uuid()` direct into the creating callback, it will get added... I believe this has something to do directly with the scoping of my variables and callback function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inject the `$uuid` into closure like this:

```php
self::creating(function ($model) use ($uuid) {
        $model->id = $uuid;
    });
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy... I tried `use $uuid` but hit an error, the parenthesis fixed it...

1:30 AM brain doesn't work the best sometimes.